# Dropdown's onchange is not triggered when selected value is set server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down list with a client side onchange that I use to populate a jQuery data table. If the value of another drop down is changed and on server side I repopulate the first drop down and set its selected value, its onchange is not triggered and data table not updated with new data.

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddlFacility', function () {debugger
    var facilityID = this.value;

    if (facilityID > -1) {
        var facCertUrl = "services/easg.asmx/GetSomethingByFacilityID";
        var facCertParams = "{ 'FacilityID': '" + facilityID + "', 'Date': '" + $("#hfStartDate").val() + "' }";
        populteTable(facCertUrl, facCertParams, tblFacCert);
    }
});

function populteTable(ws_url, parameters, table) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ws_url,
        cache: false,
        data: parameters,
    }).done(function (result) {debugger
        table.clear().draw();
        if (!result || result.d === "") {
            $('#divGrid').hide();
        }
        else {
            jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);
            table.rows.add(jResult).draw();
            table.columns([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]).visible(false);
            $('#divGrid').show();
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
        $('#divGrid').hide();
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}

var tblFacCert = $("#fcTable").DataTable({
    ....
});
```

Server side, when second drop down's value is changed:

```
protected void ddlDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sFacID = somehow_get_FacID();
    ListItem li = ddlFacility.Items.FindByValue(sFacID);

    if (null != li)
    {
        li.Selected = true; // This does not trigger onchange

        // This changes the selection and runs the onChange() event; but data table is now empty!
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ddlFacility", "$(\"#ddlFacility\").val(\"" + li.Value + "\").change();", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt trigger it because a serverside index change does not trigger a clientside index change. Either use ajax or if you still want to use postbacks, save the currently selected index into a HF and check it on page_load and trigger the change event manually..

Comment: Thanks. The change in selection of Facility drop down results in updating a jQuery data table on client side. I tried to run a script from server side to force the change() event (see update in question) which now actually does change the selected value but now my data table is empty; even when I manually change the selection (using mouse)!

Comment: U have to check your console for errors ..

Comment: I have none. Also checked network for errors. I mentioned table is empty even when I change the selection manually; that was not true. If I go through all the drop downs and select the last one (Facility DDL) manually, it populates the table. It is when I set it programatically that it just shows table header and footer and no data.

Comment: I cannot help cause I am not a fortune teller without further information.
But in your case I would debug the onchange eventhandler and check what it does or what it not does.

Comment: Thanks, What I don;t understand is that when I trace it (added "debugger" to .done part of jquery that populates the table) I can see it have the correct data (when I inspect jResult variable) but not displaying it. I will look around some more. Thanks for the help.